# How to parse an xml file in a shell script

Tags: text-processing, xml

I would like to know how can I split my data from the following format:

```
<datas>
 <data>
  <name>Name1</name>
 </data>
 <data>
  <name>Name2</name>
 </data>
</datas>
```

to the following format:

```
<data><name>Name1</name></data>
<data><name>Name2</name></data>
```

The parsed data would be sent to a Python script as follows:

```
 python script.py <data><name>Name1<name></data>
 python script.py <data><name>Name2<name></data>
```

I have tried commands like:

```
echo 'cat /datas/data' | xmllint --shell file.xml
```

but how can I pass the output in the desired format to the Python script?

Comment: Is the formatting important, or do you just want to extract all `<data>` tags and the lower tags?

Comment: thank you for helping me to make the format, Kusalananda

Comment: the format is important. Because I am passing the formatted data to a python script as arguement

Comment: It would be better if the Python script parsed the XML (using an XML parser) and extracted the bits it needed...

Comment: Do you need a generic solution (I once tried writing one for such a problem and gave up after a week) or a solution for this specific format (data->name) is what you are searching for.  A solution for this specific format can be achieved with XSLT.

Comment: currently, I am using the python to parse the XML file. 
however, there is some change in requirements 
I should pre process the xml and send the formatted data to Python, so  that I can create multiple instance of the Python script. The Python script is a robot.

Comment: So the Python script is using a proper XML parser? In that case, the format of the input is not important. There could be newlines after the `<data>` tag, for example.

Comment: oh! I thought the format you mentioned was <data><name>
there can be newlines after the data tag. 
Python is using xml.etree.ElementTree

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would preprocess the data with [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
$ xml sel -t -c '/datas/data' -nl data.xml
<data>
  <name>Name1</name>
 </data><data>
  <name>Name2</name>
 </data>
```

Then it depends on how you Python script wants to read this data. Hopefully, it's from a file or from standard input...

Comment: hmmmm can xml sel work in mac os? what library should I install to run xml command? :)

Comment: @Aryise I'm working on the command line on a MacBook Air running El Capitan.

Comment: @Aryise I'm using XMLStarlet from NetBSD's pkgsrc package system, but I believe it's available through Homebrew as well.

Comment: oh my.... I am using Mac OS X Yosemite. 
They tell me: -bash: xml: command not found 
:(

Comment: @Aryise You will have to install it through some means. Homebrew and MacPorts have *many* good utilities for Mac, and both have XMLStarlet.

Comment: oh nice, can I store them in a variable, like [<data>..</data>, <data>..</data>]
and use a for loop to extract each of them?

Comment: @Aryise Please add relevant information about how *exactly* you need to pass the data to the Python script.  Do this to the question itself.

Comment: Oh I have added the format to the question. it is supposed to be like:

        python script.py <data><name>Name1<name></data>
        python script.py <data><name>Name2<name></data>

Answer (score 6):

I'd use xslt.

the xslt stylesheet looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/datas">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="data"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="data">
  <data><name><xsl:value-of select="./name"/></name></data><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

for the transformation use the program xsltproc.

say your input file is named in.xml

the xslt stylesheet is named in.xsl

then the call is

```
 xsltproc in.xsl in.xml
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data><name>Name1</name></data>
<data><name>Name2</name></data>
```

Comment: is there a way not to modify the xml file. I dont think I am allow to modify it.
I can only change the structure of execution flow.
Currently, I am using .sh script to schedule the run for the robot.
Now the robot should be in different instance for different <data> tag. 
so I can only change the script for it. :(

Comment: you don't have to modify your input file. the xml code in my example is the stylesheet you have to provide. in my example: YOUR DATA => in.xml the stylesheet =>in.xsl. just copy the example xml code into in.xsl and it should work.

Comment: oh I see.. Although it takes additional step, it can be a backup plan if I really couldnt parse the XML directly into the way I wanted it. I should automate the process of copy the data in XML to XSL. Because the XML file that is used is dynamic.
for instance, today can be   using a.xml file but the next run can be either b or c.xml