# How to use sed, awk, or grep to delet a certain pattern but keep everything else

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I want To delete every thing but a message.
For example, if we have the following:

```
<p class="TweetTextSize  js-tweet-text tweet-text" lang="en" data-aria-label-part="0">.<a href="/TuckerCarlson" class="twitter-atreply pretty-link js-nav" dir="ltr" data-mentioned-user-id="22703645" ><s>@</s><b>TuckerCarlson</b></a>: &quot;Massive demographic change has political consequences.&quot; <a href="/hashtag/Tucker?src=hash" data-query-source="hashtag_click" class="twitter-hashtag pretty-link js-nav" dir="ltr" ><s>#</s><b>Tucker</b></a><a href="https://t.co/PKqNgaihMQ" class="twitter-timeline-link u-hidden" data-pre-embedded="true" dir="ltr" >pic.twitter.com/PKqNgaihMQ</a></p>
```

The result after using the command should look like this:

```
Massive demographic change has political consequences.
```

My attempt so far

```
sed -n "/<p class="TweetTextSize  js-tweet-text tweet-text" lang="en" data-aria-label-part="0">/,/<\/p>/p">>
```

What I am trying to do is to delete what is inside all `<> </>` pattern between `<p> </p>` and keep the rest.
I know it does not seem easy but I would still appreciate any help.

Comment: [Use an XML parser.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5419599)

Comment: While in certain case you can get sed or awk to do XML, they are usually not the best tools for the job.  As @Wildcard said get a proper XML parser.  I personally would use python, but that is just me.  See posts like : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295896/how-to-parse-an-xml-file-in-a-shell-script/295902  for other suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

The solution using [***xmstarlet***](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html) tool:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/p/text()[2]" -n file | sed 's/.*"\(.*\)"/\1/'
```

The output:

```
Massive demographic change has political consequences.
```

---

`sel` option

> sel (or select) - Select data or query XML document(s) (XPATH, etc)

`-t` --template options

`-v` option

> -v or --value-of  - print value of XPATH expression

---

`/p/text()[2]` - XPath expresssion, selects the second text node of the paragraph(the first text node is `.`)

`sed 's/.*"\(.*\)"/\1/'` - to extract the message between double quotes